# Proof clifford's theorem for curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I was dealing with the proof of clifford's theorem which is presented in Hartshorne and a part of it isn't completely clear to me. He chooses a divisor $D$ which is not $0$ or $K$ that satisfies the equality $dim|D|=\frac{degD}{2}$.
The unclear part is the following:

> So suppose now that $degD\geq 4$, hence $dim|D|\geq 2$. Fix a divisor $E\in|K-D|$, and fix two points $P,Q\in X$ such that $P\in Supp E$ and  $Q\notin Supp E$. Since $dim|D|\geq 2$, we can find a divisor $D\in |D|$ such that $P,Q\in Supp D$.

Why we can find such a divisor in $|D|$ with $P$ and $Q$ in its support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D$ is any divisor with $|D|=r>0$ and $P\in X$ is any point, then $|D-P|\geq r-1$. So, in your situation, we get $|D-P-Q|\geq 0$, which means it is non-empty. Thus, there exists an effective divisor $D'\in |D-P-Q|$, that is to say, $D\sim D'+P+Q$, which is what you want.